# .getGraphics() is returning null

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, awt, draw

My code is trying to reference a class called Grapher, this results in the .getGraphics returning a null.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestGrapher extends Grapher{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("input x/y vals");
        double xval=sc.nextDouble();
        double yval=sc.nextDouble();


        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Graph");
        Canvas canvas = new Drawing();
        canvas.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


        Grapher Maker=new Grapher();

        Maker.setPoint(xval,yval);
    }
}
```

and the Grapher class which is being extended

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Grapher extends Canvas {
    private double prvX=50;
    private double prvY=350;
    //private Graphics g;

    public void Grapher(){

    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        //this.g = g;
        //draws the graph
        g.drawString("Population Graph",150,40);
        g.drawLine(50,50,50,350);
        g.drawString("Size",10,200);
        g.drawLine(50,350,350,350);
        g.drawString("Time",150,370);

        setPoint(100,50);


    }
    public void setPoint(double xVal, double yVal){
        getGraphics().drawLine((int) this.prvX,(int)this.prvY,(int)xVal,(int)yVal);
        this.prvX=xVal;
        this.prvY=yVal;
    }
}
```

So my question is why the .getGrpahics (under SetPoint) is returning null, if I run all this on one main function and no class it works just fine, but i need to class it for a project.

Comment: You're painting wrong. Don't call getGraphics. Pass the graphics context along with the coordinates and use that. And Canvas is awt and outdated. Stick with Swing and extend `JPanel` and override `paintComponent(Graphics g);`  And the only way  you should be painting is to invoke `repaint()` or one of its variants.

Comment: I also recommend you check out [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).  In particular, [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) .  And on SO, check out questions with the `java` tag with tags such as `swing`, `graphics`, and `painting`

Comment: `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);` Also, don't mix GUI and console I/O. To get the two values, offer spinners in an option pane (or two). Easier all around.

Comment: `getGraphics().drawLine((int) this.prvX,(int)this.prvY,(int)xVal,(int)yVal)` This suggests the software needs to draw a **series** of lines. This complicates matters slightly using the custom painting approach discussed by @WJS - the app. needs to hold a list of all objects and draw them in a loop whenever `repaint()` is invoked. Alternately, you might use a `BufferedImage` (displayed in a `JLabel`) and directly call for a graphics object of the image to do painting (so that is a situation where it *does* make sense to call for the `Graphics` object and use it directly).